Unable to install a QGIS version newer than 3.22.16 on VM running Debian 12
I have just updated to a M3 Macbook and since there is no working release yet for ARM chips (tried macports install, but still many plugins do not work properly) I have created a virtual machine with UTM running Debian 12 (completely fresh install). I followed the instructions on the installation page (https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#linux)  multiple times and always end up with the same version installed: QGIS 3.22.16+dfsg-1.
I've never worked on Linux before so the whole installation process is new to me.
When I try to update the software using
sudo apt upgrade

I get the following message

The following packages have been kept back
python3-qgis-common qgis-common qgis-plugin-grass-common qgis-providers-common

When I try to install
sudo apt install qgis

The terminal tells me that this is the latest release.
I have already tried to edit the repository file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources to different URIs/Suite names but either I get an error or it installs again the version above.
When I try to update python3-qgis-common
sudo apt upgrade python3-qgis-common

I get the following error

python3-qgis-common : Depends on: libqgis-customwidgets (>= 1:3.36.3+17bookworm) but 3.22.16+dfsg-1 is supposed to be installed

What am I doing wrong?
